# Rails / CSS styling - how to seperate results from a code loop

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events app on Rails and I'm currently styling the site. I'm not using bootstrap or foundation, only skeleton & normalize grids. I'm trying to get the events displaying across the page but at the moment they're simply stacking up on top of one another. I understand why but I don't know the solution to fix this. Any assistance would be appreciated. Here's my code -

Events - index.html.erb

```
<section id="events">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <% @events.each do |event| %>


                <%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event %>

                <h2><%= link_to event.title, event %></h2>
                <h2><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h2>

            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's the code block - Events - which I'm looking to display inline with each other. No matter which CSS code I use nothing happens - the events just stack on top of each other.

```
section#events {

float: left;
display: inline;
margin-top: 20px;
margin: 10px;
```

}

Comment: Your selector applies to the 'section#events' element - if you want each "event" to float you would need to wrap it in an element and target that element instead. This has nothing to do with rails - its just how CSS works.

Comment: Many thanks. so if I wrap the code block in a div with a specific id then that should work? Will it work with display: inline; ? (I'll edit the question to remove the rails tags).